# File::Util make_dir unwanted output

Tags: perl, perl-module

when using this sub, if I pass a directory with bad characters it spits its output to the console like this:

```
PROCESS TERMINATED DUE TO ERRORS

File::Util can't use this string for �the name of a directory�.
   �ddd??---?d�
It contains illegal characters.

Illegal characters are:
   \   (backslash)
   /   (forward slash)
   :   (colon)
   |   (pipe)
   *   (asterisk)
   ?   (question mark)
   "   (double quote)
   <   (less than)
   >   (greater than)
   \t  (tab)
   \ck (vertical tabulator)
   \r  (newline CR)
   \n  (newline LF)

Origin:     This is a human error.
Solution:   A human must remove the illegal characters from this string.

ARG   _pak = File::Util
ARG   purpose = the name of a directory
ARG   string = ddd??---?d

1. File::Util::_throw
    -called at line (1343) of blib/lib/File/Util.pm (autosplit into blib/lib/auto/File/Util/make_dir.al)
       -was called with args
       -was not called to evaluate anything


2. File::Util::make_dir
    -called at line (35) of importdatafiles.pl
       -was called with args
       -was not called to evaluate anything


3. (eval)
    -called at line (35) of importdatafiles.pl
       -was called without args
       -was not called to evaluate anything
```

How to suppress this output (I just want to print "Bad" without all this detailed info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [File::Path](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/File-Path-2.08/Path.pm) qw/mkpath/? I don't know whether it runs under windows though, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure there is a way to suppress that output I mentioned above somehow.

Comment: Agreed. It's bad practice for File::Util to be writing a load of verbose comment to STDOUT (not even STDERR) and dying in a way that you can't even trap with an eval. That's not the way library code should behave.

Comment: Btw, I'm not using windows at all, but still wants to use File::Util and I'm sure there is a workaround to this.

Comment: Is this only me, or mkpath created basically anything..even when I pass: /home/user/desktop????dsdasd____dasdsada  It creates is,although this is not a valid dir name

Comment: It is a valid dir/file name under Linux. Even \n/\r is, which aggravates me to hell. Personally I prefer to use regexes that make %DE%AD%BE%EF out of anything non-alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

"Just suppressing the output" probably can be done through eval/die construct. Like this:

```
eval { make_dir (...) };
if ($@) { die "nice short error message" };
```

However, that long error message is still stunning me. It was so insulting that I mistaken it for a Windows CLI utility output, as you can see :)